# Manage config in nodejs to get variables from file and env variables

Tags: node.js

I have a configuration file in which passwords are stored and the data are used

```
'use strict';

export default {
    dbProd: {
        connectionString: 'postgres://...',
    },
    dbDev: {
        connectionString: 'postgres://...',
    },
    ...
}
```

I also have a postgresql database connection file

```
'use strict';

import { Pool } from 'pg';
import config from './../config';

export default new Pool({
    connectionString: config.dbDev.connectionString,
    ssl: true
});
```

In my `package.json` file, there are three scripts. The first to launch the project, the second to develop, and the third for the production

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/index.js",
    "devbuild": "babel src --out-dir dev-backend",
    "build": "babel src --out-dir backend"
  },
```

I need it when I collect a project for production to connect to the database via `dbProd`, and if the development was transferred to `dbDev`. How to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider to use the node-package `config` [NPM Config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config), because it makes these things much easier.

You would just need to create a `default.json` file inside a `/config` folder, which would include all of your development configs and configs that do not change either in development nor in production. The second file which you have to create would be a `production.json` files that includes all your production configs that overrides the default key:values.

In your `package.json` you simply need a start-script for the production enviroment and one for the development. This could look like this:

```
 "start": "SET NODE_ENV=production& node ./bin/www",
 "dev": "node ./bin/www",
```

By setting `NODE_ENV=production` the config module would load the default config and look inside the production-file to find out which values must be override in production mode.

A simple example of the `default config file`:

```
{
    "Services": {
      "api": {
        "username": "user",
        "password": "password",
        "base_url": "https://development.com/test"
      }
    },
    "Network": {
      "proxy": {
        "host": "http://myproxy/",
        "port": 80
      }
    }
  }
```

In case the proxy is always the same and just the API changes, the `production file` would look like this:

```
  {
    "Services": {
      "api": {
        "username": "prodUser",
        "password": "prodPassword",
        "base_url": "https://production.com/test"
      }
    }
  }
```

This can now be used in your code like this for example:

```
const config = require('config');
const serviceConfig = config.get('Services');
const networkConfig = config.get('Network');

networkConfig.get('proxy.host')+":"+networkConfig.get('proxy.port')
```

Comment: How do I use babel7 with this package?

Comment: I guess you would just have to use the `&` notation as i used to the start script

Comment: I installed the package, created two files, development.js and production.js. They only link to database connections, for development and development. I can not understand. How can I transfer this link to the database connection file depending on the type of activity?

Comment: I need in `export default new Pool ...` only `dbProd` or only `dbDev`

Comment: The files should be `.json` files.

Comment: In the documentation I read what you can in js https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Configuration-Files#file-formats

Comment: In your code you do not have to do anything different for dev or prod. If you start your application with `SET NODE_ENV=production&` the default config settings are use AND the production settings if they also exist in this file. For development mode you can just start you app as always and the default values are used

Comment: You can use `.js` but than you have to change the code of the config files. My example is for json! And json is much better for these things

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **[config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config)** package or any other popular packages that allow you to define different configs for every environment.

Using **config** you'll have to make the */config* folder where you can put all your configs per environment like following:

```
/config/development.json
/config/production.json
```

Usage:

```
 var config = require('config');
 //...
 var dbConfig = config.get('Customer.dbConfig');
 db.connect(dbConfig, ...);

 if (config.has('optionalFeature.detail')) {
   var detail = config.get('optionalFeature.detail');
   //...
 }
```

This package uses **NODE_ENV** environment variable value to determine which config to use so you'll have to set this variable before starting the application.

```
$ export NODE_ENV=production
$ node my-app.js
```

Comment: How do I use babel7 with this package?

Comment: I don't think you need any additional configurations. Just use it in your app then transpile with babel and run as usual

Comment: I can't figure out how to use babel 7 for a project?

Comment: What is the problem?